# How do I set the initialRoute for Android in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to tell to my app to start in a determined route inside the onCreate method of the MainActivity like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
    flutterView.setInitialRoute("anotherRoute") // <-- no result
}
```

But it gives no results, the dart side stills receive the standard "/" as `window.defaultRouteName`

If I set it before calling super, it gives me NullPointer:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    flutterView.setInitialRoute("anotherRoute") // <-- NullPointer
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
}
```

Comment: you can not use `initialRoute` on MaterialApp ?

Comment: The "initialRoute" value will come from outside Flutter (like a Notification)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override *createFlutterView* method

```
  override fun createFlutterView(context: Context): FlutterView {
    val matchParent = WindowManager.LayoutParams(-1, -1)
    val view = FlutterView(this, null as AttributeSet?, this.createFlutterNativeView())
    view.setInitialRoute("/route2")
    view.layoutParams = matchParent

    this.setContentView(view)
    return view
  }
```